# Magento 2 with Stock and Order Management Software

Tags: magento2, stock

Hopefully someone can help with this

I am running stock management software.
Currently I am experiencing this isse

Item Stock 3
Sellable Stock 3

Item sells

Item Stock 3
Sellable Stock 2

So far so good

This then feeds through to the order an stock management software
It pings back the new stock level to the various platforms we sell on and magento 2 then looks like this

Item Stock 2 
Sellable Stock 1

When I ship the item it shows the below

Item Stock 1
Sellable Stock 1

Basically it is double selling because it is being fed a new stock level from the order and stock management software

Any ideas how I can stop this happening?
If i set manage stock to no then it is causing items to not go out of stock

Thank you for any advice